# Wieder- oder zurückkommen?

Tags: phrase, expression

In einem Dialog aus [meinem Lehrbuch](http://www.amazon.fr/Communiquer-en-allemand-Bernard-Straub/dp/2266035975/ref=sr_1_fkmr1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1454513754&sr=1-2-fkmr1&keywords=allemand%3A+communiquer+Presse+Pocket+langues+pour+tous) sagt eine Frau, deren Mann auf Reise fährt:

> *komm heil wieder*.

Ich hätte

> *komm heil zurück*

erwartet.
Was denkt ihr: Täusche ich mich oder liegt da ein Bedeutungsunterschied vor?

Comment: Ich hätte an dieser Stelle tatsächlich "zurück" gewählt. "Ich komme wieder " würde ich eher für jemanden verwenden, der normalerweise wo anders ist, aber wieder hier vorbei kommt. Anders herum würde ich "Ich komme zurück" verwenden, wenn ich normalerweise hier bin, aber vorübergehend woanders hin gehe, um danach wieder zurückzukommen. Es könnte aber auch eine Verkürzung von "Komm heil wieder zurück" sein.

Comment: Komm heil wieder zurück! ;)

Comment: @Burki: Es freut mich, dass wir darüber einer Meinung sind. *Wieder zurück* (auch von Iris vorgeschlagen)  ist tatsächlich eine risikolose Variante  :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Der Unterschied ist äußerst subtil, und eigentlich nicht wirklich vorhanden.

### wiederkommen

Das kann zwei verschiedene Bedeutungen haben:

**zum wiederholten Male kommen**

> Den Mann mit dem sonderbaren Mantel habe ich schon oft gesehen. Ich bin sicher, er wird auch morgen wiederkommen.

**kommen, um einen alten Zustand erneut herzustellen**

> Wenn Papa wiederkommt, wird er sich darum kümmern.
>   Sobald der Regen wiederkommt wird hier alles aufblühen.

### zurückkommen

Zurückkommen hat ebenfalls zwei Bedeutungen:

Zum Ausgangspunkt einer Reise gelangen. Gegenteil von Aufbrechen bzw. Weggehen, Wegfahren:

> Mach dir keine Sorgen, früher oder später wird er wieder zu dir zurückkommen.

Im übertragenen Sinn, wenn das Gesprächsthema gewechselt wurde:

> Ich möchte wieder auf den Grund der Besprechung zurückkommen.

---

Meiner Auffassung nach stimmen die zweite Wiederkommen-Bedeutung (Herstellen des alten Zustands) und die erste Zurückkommen-Bedeutung (Erneut an den Beginn einer Reise gelangen) so weit überein, dass praktisch kein Unterschied feststellbar ist. Da die beiden Floskeln aus der Frage genau diesen Bedeutungen entsprechen, sehe ich keine Bedeutungsunterschied.

Answer (score 3):

Laut [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/wiederkommen) ist in dem geschilderten Fall die Bedeutung absolut identisch; beide Ausdrücke sind synonym.

> ***wiederkommen***
>
> 1. a) **zurückkommen**
>
>    b) noch einmal kommen
> 2. noch einmal auftreten, sich noch einmal ereignen

Comment: Danke, adjan, du hast meine Frage vollständig beantwortet. Leider konnte ich nur eine Antwort akzeptieren, und jede der zwei Wahlen  die ich treffen konnte ist gegenüber der anderen ungerecht  ...